# How to install one contract many times on different nodes in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am facing a scenario in which all nodes in a network need to have the same smart contract installed and instantiated on them. But for privacy reasons, I want to keep them on different channels. In other words each two peers have their own channel. But the business logic and condititions to trade are the same for all of them. Therefore, the smart contract is the same.

Is it a way that I can install the smart contract once on a node for all the channels it belongs to? Lets say there are 400 peers in a network. and it is a full mesh. Therefore each node belongs to 399 channels. There is one smart contract per channel which makes it 399 smart contracts needed to be installed on each node. But these contracts all have the same logic and are the same. I would like to know if it is possible to have a reference to a smart contract, and have it installed just once, but for all the channels a node belongs to. Moreover, if in future there is a need to change the smart contract then a lot of duplicatre work needs to be done which is bad design decision.

Please note that for some reason **I do not want to use ACL** , as I want to be 100% sure the privacy of data is realized. Therefore, I would like to implement this scenario just by channels without ACL.

Also please consider I am using composer for development. So I would like to know if it is possible to realize it both in Hyperledger Fabric and Composer

Thank you for your attention. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Composer chaincode using the command `composer network install --card <your admin card> --archiveFile <your archive file>` for any peers and channels specified in `connection.json`.

You can specify one smart-contract for two channels like so (you can use this principle for any number of channels):

```
"channels": {
        "first": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer0.ex.ru"   
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.ex.ru": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },

                "peer0.org2.ex.ru": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }

            },
       "second": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer0.ex.ru"   
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.ex.ru": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },

                "peer1.org2.ex.ru": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }

            }
        }
```

*(please don't forget to specify the remaining fields)*

After that you create admin card:

```
composer card create -p connection.json -u <identity name> -c <public key path> -k <secret key path> -r <admin card name> -r <role> -f <card filename>
```

Then import it to wallet store:

```
composer card import -f <admin card file> --card <admin card name>
```

Create archive file:

```
composer archive create -t dir -n .
```

Install:

```
composer network install --card <admin card name> --archiveFile <archive file produced in the previous step>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In connection.json where is the smart contract? As I understood we defined channel "first" with two peers and one orderer. I would like to know how can I install all the smart contract once on one peer. Lets say there are 100 exactly same smart contracts that I need to install on a peer. DO I need to mention them one by one like in the connection.json file above?

Comment: Al;so I appreciate if you kindly mention where the specific smart contract in connection.json file is. Is it using logic.js in lib forlder by default?

Comment: @E.Erfan You must specify only the channels and peers in connection.json. Smart contract is defined in .bna (wich includes logic.js, yes). Just try it and report here, if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*"Is it a way that I can install the smart contract once on a node for all the channels it belongs to? Lets say there are 400 peers in a network. and it is a full mes*h" - Yes. You install the chaincode once - you can instantiate / start that [same] chaincode on the channels as you've described it above.

Note also (in Hyperledger Fabric 1.2) you can read more on the new channel Private Data feature (private data collections and where data is stored) released in Fabric 1.2 https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/private-data/private-data.html?highlight=private%20data

Comment: The OP mentioned he uses Hyperledger Composer for development. Unfortunately, in Composer, you can't install once and instantiate multiple times. Besides, Private Data (a.k.a. Side DB) is not available in Composer unless the Native API feature is used.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- I went through the documents of Fabric, it is mentioned that channels are isolated from one another. But as Paul said does it mean I can install chaincode once on node, not channel but node itself, and instantiate it multiple times on different channels?

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- you also mentioned it is not possible in composer to install once and intantiate multiple times. Do you recommend using composer for production altogether?

Comment: No, I don't think Composer is good enough for production. However, it is not bad for PoC (Proof-of-Concept) since you do not need to install anything. Just load it into the browser by visiting here: http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/. All code is executed on the browser, and there is no blockchain behind. After modeling, the code could be exported to a BNA archive and installed on a real blockchain.

Comment: @E.Erfan The documentation is referring to Fabric chaincode (Golang or JavaScript using the "stub"), not Composer chaincode (CTO + JS + ACL). Fabric chaincode could be installed once and instantiated multiple times. But I don't think Composer chaincode could do the same. You could think of Composer as an "Easy Mode" of Hyperledger Fabric.